# Override/Customize mixins in Boostrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, sass, bootstrap-4, less

I am trying to customize the badge class in Bootstrap 4. What I am trying to achieve is to display all badges with an outline (similar to .btn-outline-*). Right now, I am (naively) trying to do this by "overriding" the mixing in a separate stylesheet as follows:

```
@mixin badge-variant($bg) {
  //color: color-yiq($bg); #original
  color: $bg;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $bg;

  &[href] {
    @include hover-focus {
      //background-color: darken($bg, 10%); #original
      background-color: $bg;
    }
  }
}

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

How come this isn't working and what can I do to customize the mixin (without editing the original file)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, but remember you have to `@import bootstrap` first and then generate the `badge-*` classes...

```
@import "bootstrap";

@mixin badge-variant($bg) {
  color: $bg;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $bg;

  &[href] {
    @include hover-focus {
      background-color: $bg;
    }
  }
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .badge-#{$color} {
    @include badge-variant($value);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Iq1RJ96AmW

Comment: I just got what the he asked for. Thanks for your pro tip Zim. Count me for an up vote :)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! @Anjana - Thank you too, and sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

How about overidding `.badge` class like this and have `border`.

[image]

**CSS**

```
.badge {
      border: 2px solid #ff0000
 }
```

**Sample HTML which contains badges,**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h1>
      <h2>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h2>
      <h3>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h3>
      <h4>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h4>
      <h5>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h5>
      <h6>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**An example,**

https://codepen.io/anjanasilva/pen/MPmxJd

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my question was regarding the mixin and how/if it is possible to edit that (without touching the original file). Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I am bit unsure about what you meant by mixing. The above example is not touching the original file. It is using the existing class provided by `bootstrap4` and customizing the way we want. As in the above example, I have added a border by overriding the `.badge` class.

Comment: In the essence, I want to to be able to use variables when editing, for instance, badges. Thus, I thought that overriding the mixin will make sense. Your solution would require me to override all badge classes: badge-primary, badge-secondary, badge-primary:hover etc. which is something I want to avoid if possible

Comment: No you don't have to override all `badge-*` classes. All you need to override is the class `.badge` .Don't forget that all badge classes such as `badge-primary, badge-secondary` and so on will have `.badge` class along with it. So for instance, if you want to use `badge-primary` it will be `badge badge-primary`. However, if you want to have specific requirements one for the `badge-primary`, one for the `badge-secondary` and so on, then you will have to override them individually. Did I make it clear for you?

Comment: @AnjanaSilva - I think the OP wants to use a SASS mixin, not CSS overrides.

Comment: @Zim : Thank you. I just got what you meant. :)